# Adding a tooltip in a Dojo Select

Tags: javascript, dojo, tooltip, dijit.form

I would like to add a tooltip to the items in a Dojo Select. This code adds a tooltip when the store is contained in the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
    @import "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
    @import "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.0/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>

    <script>
    require(["dijit/form/Select",
      "dojo/store/Memory",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function (Select, Memory) {

        var store = new Memory({
        data: [
          { id: "foo", label: '<div tooltip="Foo Tooltip" onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">FOO</div>' },
          { id: "bar", label: '<div tooltip="Bar Tooltip" onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">Bar</div>' }
        ]
        });

        var s = new Select({
        store: store,
        labelType: 'html',
        labelAttr: 'label'
        }, "target");
        s.startup();
    });

    function showTooltip(el) {
        dijit.showTooltip(el.getAttribute('tooltip'), el);
    }

    function hideTooltip(el) {
        dijit.hideTooltip(el);
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, in my application, my store is in a separate module (stores.js).

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        priority: [
            { id: "foo", label: '<div tooltip="Foo Tooltip" onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">FOO</div>' },
            { id: "bar", label: '<div tooltip="Bar Tooltip" onmouseover="showTooltip(this)" onmouseout="hideTooltip(this)">Bar</div>' }
        ]
     };
};
```

I set the module in the require ("modules/stores") and put the alias in the function (Stores) and create my select using this code.

```
new Select({
    id: "cboPriority",
    store: new Memory({ data: Stores.priority }),
    labelType: 'html',
    labelAttr: 'label'
}, "divPriority").startup();
```

I've tried adding the showTooltip and hideTooltip functions in the module, but I still get the console error "ReferenceError: showTooltip is not defined". What is the proper way of setting up the script and the module so I can show the tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to set up inline `onmouseover` event handlers on elements via your label strings.  This is going to attempt to call a global `showTooltip` function, and no such function exists - your `showTooltip` function is enclosed within your require factory function.

Given that you are creating an HTML label with a node containing an attribute indicating the text to display, a better option in this specific case would be to use dojo/on's [event delegation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#event-delegation) to hook up a single event handler for mouseover and another for mouseout:

```
var dropdownNode = s.dropDown.domNode;
on(dropdownNode, '[data-tooltip]:mouseover', function () {
    Tooltip.show(this.getAttribute('data-tooltip'), this);
});
on(dropdownNode, '[data-tooltip]:mouseout', function () {
    Tooltip.hide(this);
});
```

(`Tooltip` in the above code refers to the `dijit/Tooltip` module, and I elected to use a data-attribute which would at least be valid HTML5.)

To be quite honest, I'd prefer avoiding embedding HTML in data to begin with, but this is likely the shortest path from where you are to where you want to be.

Comment: Originally, I had the items in the store module set up like this: `{ id: "foo", label: "FOO", tip: "Foo Tooltip"}` and tried using the Tooltip as shown in the example @Eric used, but I couldn't figure out the correct CSS selector to use.